React Native Auto Horizontal Scroll
Is there a way to implement auto infinite horizontal scrolling in react native where we have a list that shows partners/companies just like the image attached.Link
I had tried using basic CSS and react-native-animated, but am clueless how to get this effect.

try to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-reanimated-carousel on autoplay & loop and adjust the settings so that it translates just like you want

For infinite scroll, you can use  this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-infinite-looping-scroll

Install dependencies:
npm install react-native-snap-carousel

Create a new component file e.g. InfinitePartnerCorousel.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';

const InfinitePartnerCarousel = ({ data, partnerWidth, partnerSpacing }) => {
  const [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState(0);

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    // ... Your component to render each partner/company
  };

  // Helper function to create dummy items for infinite scrolling effect
  const createDummyData = (dataLength) => {
    const dummyItems = Math.ceil((Carousel.defaultProps.sliderWidth - partnerWidth) / (partnerWidth + partnerSpacing));
    return [...Array(dummyItems)].fill(null);
  };

  const combinedData = [...createDummyData(data.length), ...data, ...createDummyData(data.length)];

  return (
    <View style={styles.carouselContainer}>
      <Carousel
        layout={'default'}
        data={combinedData}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        sliderWidth={Carousel.defaultProps.sliderWidth}
        itemWidth={partnerWidth}
        inactiveSlideScale={1} // Maintain consistent item size
        inactiveSlideOpacity={1} // Maintain consistent item visibility
        onSnapToSlide={setActiveSlide}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  carouselContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default InfinitePartnerCarousel;

Renders the Carousel component from react-native-snap-carousel with the following key points:

layout: Set to 'default' for a standard horizontal carousel layout.
data: Uses the combinedData array.
renderItem: Calls the custom renderItem function to render each item.
sliderWidth: Inherits the default width from Carousel.
itemWidth: Sets the width of each partner item.
inactiveSlideScale and inactiveSlideOpacity: Set to 1 to maintain consistent size and visibility of all items during scrolling, creating a smooth infinite effect.
onSnapToSlide: Updates the activeSlide state when the user snaps to a new slide.

Usage in your app:
import InfinitePartnerCarousel from './InfinitePartnerCarousel';

const MyScreen = () => {
  const partnerData = [
    // Your partner/company data objects
  ];

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <InfinitePartnerCarousel
        data={partnerData}
        partnerWidth={200} // Adjust as needed
        partnerSpacing={10} // Adjust as needed
      />
    </View>
  );
};


Will this scroll automatically? I don't see a prop that can help with auto infinite scrolling.
